# randomly sample groups in groups

Tags: r, grouping

Given is a data frame with a column 'Date' (yyyy-mm-dd).

```
        Date
1       2015-01-01
2       2015-01-01
3       2015-01-01
4       2015-01-01
5       2015-01-01
6       2015-01-24
7       2015-01-24
8       2015-01-30
9       2015-01-30
...
996     2015-12-17
997     2015-12-17
998     2015-12-31
999     2015-12-31
```

Now I want to sample the data frame by Date within each month. If the Date in diffrent rows is the same it should be still grouped after the sample.

The result I'am looking for could be like this:

```
        Date
1       2015-01-24
2       2015-01-24
3       2015-01-01
4       2015-01-01
5       2015-01-01
6       2015-01-01
7       2015-01-01
8       2015-01-30
9       2015-01-30
...
996     2015-12-31
997     2015-12-31
998     2015-12-17
999     2015-12-17
```

Comment: Perhaps `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(lubdidate::month(Date)) %>% sample_frac(replace= TRUE)`

Comment: @Axeman what will happen if there is more than 1 year?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Use `group_by(lubridate::year(Date), lubridate::month(Date))` instead?

Comment: Please make your example reproducible with the code you've tried so far and doesn't appear to work. That way you demonstrate that you've tried to solve the problem on your own. The example helps you think about your data really hard, which is always a plus.

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr` and `padr` this is a solution

```
library(dplyr)
library(padr)

# make some data 
x <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), length.out = 730, by = "day")) %>% 
   sample_frac(0.8) %>% arrange(Date)

x %>% thicken("month") %>% 
  group_by(Date_month) %>% 
  sample_n(10)
```

Comment: Accounts for the fact that months come from various years. Works like a charm.